# CascadingParameter via AddCascadingValue won't get updated

Tags: .net-8.0, cascadingparameter, cascadingvalue

I have added a Cascading Parameter

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(s => new CascadingValueSource<int>("someName", 1, false));
```

my Home Component is this:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

Test int is @myTestInt .

<button onclick="@testclick">button</button>

<Test>
    
</Test>

@code{

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "someName")]
    public int myTestInt { get; set; } = 0;

    private void testclick()
    {
        myTestInt = 5;
    }
}
```

Test Component looks like this

```
<h3>test</h3>

myparameter is @myparameter

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "someName")]
    public int myparameter { get; set; }
}
```

When I click the Button in Home Component and update the myTestInt variable, i'd expect the parameter update to be propagated to the Test Component. But it does not update.

I used ServerSide Rendering with `prerender: false` and adjusted Program.cs in the Server Project.

Any advice appreciated.

Additional Information: I hacked a bit around the Problem and it seems that here https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components/CascadingValueSource.cs,f0dc3cb82472303a,references the Subscribers list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some closed Issues on CascadingValues in Github here is how it is intended to work:

Create some Service you register the `CascadingValueSource<T>` with like this:

```
public class TriggerUpdate<T>
{
    private CascadingValueSource<T> source = null!;
    public void SetCascadingValueSource(CascadingValueSource<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public async Task Trigger(T newValue)
    {
        await source.NotifyChangedAsync(newValue);
    }
}
```

When registering the CascadingValueSource in Startup, set the source in the TriggerUpdate class like this

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<TriggerUpdate<int>>();
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(s =>
{
    var triggerService = (TriggerUpdate<int>) s.GetService(typeof(TriggerUpdate<int>))!;
    var source = new CascadingValueSource<int>(1, false);
    triggerService!.SetCascadingValueSource(source);
    return source;
});
```

in the component, when setting a new Value on the CascadingParameter, do it like this:

```
[Inject] public TriggerUpdate<int> TriggerUpdate { get; set; } 

[CascadingParameter]
public int myTestInt { get; set; } = 0;

private async Task testclick()
{
    await TriggerUpdate.Trigger(5);
}
```

It's not perfect but along these lines updates can be propagated.